# VS 2015 Duplicate Subs Automatically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently coding a new project on vb.net in VS 2015 and I found a curious situation. Every time When I compile the project, it duplicates sub-procedures, but only the ones that handles various events.

For example:

```
Private Sub Review_HoverView(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Review.MouseHover, Review.MouseEnter, Review.MouseMove, ReviewLbl.MouseHover, ReviewLbl.MouseEnter, ReviewLbl.MouseMove
    Review.Image = Global.Received.My.Resources.ReviewHover
    ReviewLbl.ForeColor = Color.Green
End Sub

Private Sub Review_NormalView(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Review.MouseLeave, Review.MouseUp, ReviewLbl.MouseLeave, ReviewLbl.MouseUp
    Review.Image = Global.Received.My.Resources.Review
    ReviewLbl.ForeColor = Color.Blue
End Sub

Private Sub Review_ClickView(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Review.MouseDown, ReviewLbl.MouseDown
    Review.Image = Global.Received.My.Resources.ReviewClick
    ReviewLbl.ForeColor = Color.LightBlue
End Sub

Private Sub Review_ClickView(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ReviewLbl.MouseDown, Review.MouseDown

End Sub

Private Sub Review_HoverView(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ReviewLbl.MouseMove, ReviewLbl.MouseHover, ReviewLbl.MouseEnter, Review.MouseMove, Review.MouseHover, Review.MouseEnter

End Sub

Private Sub Review_NormalView(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ReviewLbl.MouseUp, ReviewLbl.MouseLeave, Review.MouseUp, Review.MouseLeave

End Sub
```

It's annoying, since I have to delete these lines each time that are generated.

Anyone know why and how can I avoid this situation?

Thank you in advance for your kind support.

Comment: Did you by any chance deleted the controls and added the `Handles` manually? Can you add more details on how you created the controls and how the duplicate subs shows? The one I can think of causing it is the `Handle` was deleted from the `sub`. Then you selected the `event` from the `control` resulting to a new `sub` of that event.

Comment: Actually it's really funny since the duplicate subs only appear after I compile the project.

I'm using the designer to create the controls, then I create the handle sub manually.

The funny thing is that if I use the AddHandle method the code doesn't duplicate automatically. I think its VS2015 bug.